# Sympy won't evaluate equation without free variables

Tags: python, sympy

I have an equation of one variable that I'd like to evaluate at a given value of that variable, but after calling `.subs(...)` and getting an equation of zero free symbols, sympy refuses to simplify it to a number. However, if I convert it to a string (as I tried in order to post this question) and then convert it back using `sympy.sympify`, the expression evaluates just fine. Where could I be going wrong?

`equation.subs('F', 5)` gives me the equation back with F replaced by 5. This does not simplify to a number, even though I believe it should because it has no free symbols.

`equation.subs('F', 5).free_symbols` is the empty set

`sympy.sympify(str(equation)).subs('F', 5)` gives me a number as a result

Here is the result of `str(equation)`: `'(384.905148220275*(0.170386609849201*F - 1)**2 - 1.00032489968052e-5)**2.6312329349372*0.131712523957535 - (3.34281484313696*F - 19.6189996743023 + 2.55848312109802)**(-1)*0.791887145750515'`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that sympy by default will only convert expressions to numbers if the numbers are exact. `simplify(sqrt(17))` will stay unchanged.  On the other hand, if the expression contains floats, e.g. `simplify(sqrt(17.0))` it will be converted to float, as floats are imprecise by construction.  If you really want a numeric result, you can use `nsimplify(sqrt(17))`.

Comment: `((384.905148220275*(0.170386609849201*F - 1)**2 - 1.00032489968052e-5)**2.6312329349372*0.131712523957535 - (3.34281484313696*F - 19.6189996743023 + 2.55848312109802)**(-1)*0.791887145750515).subs(F,5)` gives `38.3318296801769`, at least when using the latest sympy version (1.10.1).  There is no conversion to string nor an explicit call to `simplify()` or `nsimplify()` involved.  Can you clarify your question, preferably with a simple fully reproducible example?

Comment: It's not clear what you call an Equation to me. As others said, we need an example, because I suspect you mix up some vocabulary, between expression, equations, functions...

Answer (score 0):

SymPy will avoid converting non-Rational numbers to Floats but you can request evaluation:

```
>>> from sympy import sqrt
>>> n = sqrt(2) + 0.1; n
0.1 + sqrt(2)
>>> n.is_number
True
>>> n.evalf(3)  # eval to 3 digits
1.51
```